# How to add joined column from nested query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add joined column from nested query using `whereHas` statement like this:

```php
$options = Option::whereHas('texts', function($query) {
        $query->addSelect('options_text.text');
    })->where(['active' => 1, ])
    ->first();
```

But as result `$options->text` gives `null`. Is there any ideas how to do this? Without making all query using `->join()`.

My model is fine, here is my relation:

```php
public function texts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OptionText', 'option_id', 'id');
}
```

I use it in different situations and is works correct.

Comment: I think this is relationship query right? Please add your both model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `with([$relation => $callback])` notation. Here you can specify that only one column should be loaded:

```
$options = Option::query()
    ->with(['texts' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'text']);
    }])
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->first();
```

Don't forget to also select the `id` column (or your key column, if that isn't `id`) because otherwise, Eloquent doesn't know which related object belongs to which parent.

If you also need a constraint on the related table, you can simply add it to your query:

```
$options = Option::query()
    ->with(['texts' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'text']);
    }])
    ->whereHas('texts', function ($query) {
        $query->where('text', 'LIKE', '%dog%');
    })
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->first();
```